# SSRS - No Rows Formatting Dropped in PDF

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2016

In SSRS, I have a bunch of subreports in a report.  Within each subreport, I have a No Rows message. For each of those messages I have the TextAlign set to Center.  When I run the report in the Design View in Visual Studio or within the Report Viewer in a browser, the TextAlign property is respected; however, when Print Preview within Visual Studio or export to PDF from Visual Studio or from a browser, all formatting of the No Rows message is dropped.  Does anyone know why this occurs?  I've put before and after pictures below.  The first picture is in the report viewer and the second is in a PDF export.[image: Before]

[image: After]

Comment: At a guess I'd say the font you've chose is not supported in pdf

Comment: Sorry, Joker font was just used to make it really obvious what was happening.  The issue persists regardless of font.  Arial is the default, and the Centering of the text is stripped when using that font as well.

Comment: Well, no answer was ever found.  It's just something that happens with Reporting Services when you export to PDF, unfortunately.